# Processing output from cmdline via a Python script

Tags: python, scripting, process

I'm trying to use the subprocess module with Python 2.6 in order to run a command and get its output. The command is typically ran like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin/kamctl fifo profile_get_size myprofile | awk -F ':: ' '{print $2}'
```

What's the best way to use the subprocess module in my script to execute that command with those arguments and get the return value from the command? I'm using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want the output, the return value (AKA status code), or both?

If the amount of data emitted by the pipeline on stdout and/or stderr is not too large, it's pretty simple to get "all of the above":

```
import subprocess

s = """/usr/local/sbin/kamctl fifo profile_get_size myprofile | awk -F ':: ' '{print $2}'"""

p = subprocess.Popen(s, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate()

print 'out: %r' % out
print 'err: %r' % err
print 'status: %r' % p.returncode
```

If you have to deal with potentially huge amounts of output, it takes a bit more code -- doesn't look like you should have that problem, judging from the pipeline in question.

Comment: Ok to ask why you're using shell=True here as well as subprocess.PIPE? thanks for the rest.

Comment: You need a shell to interpret and properly execute the pipes _inside_ the string; and you need `subprocess.PIPE` for the overall `stdout` of the string of commands (as executed by the shell) to come back to your Python program.

Answer (score 2):

f.e. stdout you can get like this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> process = subprocess.Popen("echo 'test'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> process.wait()
0
>>> process.stdout.read()
'test\n'
```

Comment: If you just want to check that the call succeeded (not what you're trying to do, but it's good to know) you can use subprocess.check_call() - this will raise an exception if the exit code is not 0.